# Perl Decode JSON - Not an ARRAY referencce

Tags: json, perl

Getting error "Not an ARRAY reference" when trying to print my hash. Not sure where I am going wrong. IS there a way to print the decoded json in such a way that it makes identfying the hash elements easier?

```
use JSON qw( decode_json );  

my $owm_json= <<'__EOI__';
{"cod":"200","city":{"id":"4270936","name":"Bazine","coord":{"lon":-99.6935,"lat":38.4421},"country":"United States of America","population":0},"cnt":65,"model":"OWM","list":{"0":{"dt":1390615200,"main":{"temp":39.63,"temp_min":39.69,"temp_max":43.7,"pressure":950.95,"humidity":62.4},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":73,"low":0,"middle":6,"high":72},"wind":{"speed":15.98,"deg":269,"gust":13.8},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"1":{"dt":1390626000,"main":{"temp":40.89,"temp_min":39.69,"temp_max":43.7,"pressure":951.79,"humidity":54.7},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":82,"low":0,"middle":3,"high":82},"wind":{"speed":16.78,"deg":290,"gust":16.5},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"2":{"dt":1390636800,"main":{"temp":41.45,"temp_min":40.91,"temp_max":41.72,"pressure":952.77,"humidity":47.7},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"clouds":{"all":35,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":35},"wind":{"speed":16.63,"deg":314,"gust":18.7},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"3":{"dt":1390647600,"main":{"temp":39.81,"temp_min":39.83,"temp_max":41.72,"pressure":953.7,"humidity":48.9},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"clouds":{"all":32,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":32},"wind":{"speed":14.13,"deg":314,"gust":16.5},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"4":{"dt":1390658400,"main":{"temp":40.51,"temp_min":38.5,"temp_max":40.53,"pressure":954.95,"humidity":50.3},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"clouds":{"all":23,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":23},"wind":{"speed":12.79,"deg":318,"gust":13.9},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"5":{"dt":1390669200,"main":{"temp":51.67,"temp_min":38.5,"temp_max":51.66,"pressure":955.03,"humidity":44.3},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"clouds":{"all":18,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":18},"wind":{"speed":14.49,"deg":348,"gust":10.1},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"6":{"dt":1390680000,"main":{"temp":54.99,"temp_min":51.75,"temp_max":55,"pressure":952.14,"humidity":40.3},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":1,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":1},"wind":{"speed":8.45,"deg":326,"gust":7.5},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"7":{"dt":1390690800,"main":{"temp":46.15,"temp_min":45.82,"temp_max":55.35,"pressure":950.37,"humidity":53},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"02d"}],"clouds":{"all":10,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":10},"wind":{"speed":5.05,"deg":233,"gust":3.3},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"8":{"dt":1390701600,"main":{"temp":45.1,"temp_min":45.1,"temp_max":47.71,"pressure":948.92,"humidity":53.8},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":12.77,"deg":235,"gust":9.8},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"9":{"dt":1390712400,"main":{"temp":43.43,"temp_min":43.41,"temp_max":47.71,"pressure":947.31,"humidity":56.4},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":14.21,"deg":243,"gust":12.5},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"10":{"dt":1390723200,"main":{"temp":41.38,"temp_min":41.43,"temp_max":43.41,"pressure":946.75,"humidity":59},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":14.52,"deg":257,"gust":13.9},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"11":{"dt":1390734000,"main":{"temp":39.83,"temp_min":39.4,"temp_max":43.41,"pressure":946.52,"humidity":56.8},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":11.66,"deg":321,"gust":11.7},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"12":{"dt":1390744800,"main":{"temp":41.22,"temp_min":39.16,"temp_max":41.25,"pressure":947.87,"humidity":50.3},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":9.37,"deg":327,"gust":8},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"13":{"dt":1390755600,"main":{"temp":51.73,"temp_min":39.16,"temp_max":51.76,"pressure":947.62,"humidity":34.6},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":11.36,"deg":346,"gust":7.7},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"14":{"dt":1390766400,"main":{"temp":53.58,"temp_min":51.85,"temp_max":53.64,"pressure":945.56,"humidity":30.5},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":12.48,"deg":345,"gust":8.4},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"15":{"dt":1390777200,"main":{"temp":46.44,"temp_min":46.4,"temp_max":53.64,"pressure":948.09,"humidity":39},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":11.69,"deg":14,"gust":10.1},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"16":{"dt":1390788000,"main":{"temp":37.4,"temp_min":37.36,"temp_max":46.4,"pressure":954.84,"humidity":54.9},"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13n"}],"clouds":{"all":66,"low":66,"middle":19,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":24.34,"deg":17,"gust":15.1},"snow":{"3h":0.12},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"17":{"dt":1390798800,"main":{"temp":27.99,"temp_min":27.97,"temp_max":46.4,"pressure":959.47,"humidity":33.9},"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13n"}],"clouds":{"all":80,"low":63,"middle":57,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":21.56,"deg":10,"gust":12.7},"snow":{"3h":0.1},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"18":{"dt":1390809600,"main":{"temp":22.53,"temp_min":22.55,"temp_max":27.95,"pressure":961.66,"humidity":27.8},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":99,"low":8,"middle":99,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":17.02,"deg":2,"gust":10.3},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"19":{"dt":1390820400,"main":{"temp":20.61,"temp_min":20.57,"temp_max":27.95,"pressure":962.45,"humidity":23.1},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":100,"low":8,"middle":100,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":13.67,"deg":2,"gust":8.5},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"20":{"dt":1390831200,"main":{"temp":20.32,"temp_min":20.01,"temp_max":20.55,"pressure":964.61,"humidity":21.3},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":100,"low":44,"middle":100,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":10.04,"deg":14,"gust":5.9},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"21":{"dt":1390842000,"main":{"temp":23.4,"temp_min":20.01,"temp_max":23.4,"pressure":965.27,"humidity":17.9},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":100,"low":52,"middle":100,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":6.83,"deg":6,"gust":4.2},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"22":{"dt":1390852800,"main":{"temp":25.48,"temp_min":23.4,"temp_max":25.54,"pressure":963.17,"humidity":17.4},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":100,"low":44,"middle":100,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":4.73,"deg":346,"gust":3.5},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"23":{"dt":1390863600,"main":{"temp":24.8,"temp_min":23.4,"temp_max":25.63,"pressure":963.34,"humidity":19.6},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":100,"low":39,"middle":100,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":3.67,"deg":40,"gust":2},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"24":{"dt":1390874400,"main":{"temp":23.34,"temp_min":23.36,"temp_max":24.73,"pressure":964.88,"humidity":21},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":100,"low":3,"middle":100,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":5.23,"deg":115,"gust":2.9},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"25":{"dt":1390885200,"main":{"temp":20.53,"temp_min":20.53,"temp_max":24.73,"pressure":965.28,"humidity":25.9},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":96,"low":2,"middle":96,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":5.66,"deg":138,"gust":3.8},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"26":{"dt":1390896000,"main":{"temp":18.52,"temp_min":18.54,"temp_max":20.08,"pressure":964.39,"humidity":41.1},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":1,"low":0,"middle":1,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":6.39,"deg":171,"gust":4.6},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"27":{"dt":1390906800,"main":{"temp":18.68,"temp_min":18.41,"temp_max":20.08,"pressure":963.68,"humidity":67.5},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"02n"}],"clouds":{"all":4,"low":0,"middle":4,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":6.89,"deg":201,"gust":5},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"28":{"dt":1390917600,"main":{"temp":23.43,"temp_min":18.88,"temp_max":23.41,"pressure":964.4,"humidity":75.5},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":{"all":37,"low":7,"middle":33,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":10.26,"deg":220,"gust":7.5},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"29":{"dt":1390928400,"main":{"temp":33.31,"temp_min":18.88,"temp_max":33.31,"pressure":963.48,"humidity":41.3},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":{"all":45,"low":29,"middle":17,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":12.1,"deg":242,"gust":6.9},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"30":{"dt":1390939200,"main":{"temp":37.06,"temp_min":33.48,"temp_max":37.02,"pressure":960.5,"humidity":31.6},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"clouds":{"all":12,"low":12,"middle":0,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":7.17,"deg":284,"gust":5},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"31":{"dt":1390950000,"main":{"temp":27,"temp_min":26.96,"temp_max":37.02,"pressure":961.66,"humidity":53.9},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"02d"}],"clouds":{"all":6,"low":6,"middle":0,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":9.68,"deg":38,"gust":6.2},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"32":{"dt":1390960800,"main":{"temp":17.92,"temp_min":18,"temp_max":26.92,"pressure":962.49,"humidity":78.9},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":9.59,"deg":66,"gust":6.8},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"33":{"dt":1390971600,"main":{"temp":17.22,"temp_min":16.92,"temp_max":26.92,"pressure":961.43,"humidity":73.3},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":6.13,"deg":101,"gust":3.9},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"34":{"dt":1390982400,"main":{"temp":20.05,"temp_min":17.28,"temp_max":19.99,"pressure":957.98,"humidity":60.7},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":7.78,"deg":161,"gust":5.9},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"35":{"dt":1390993200,"main":{"temp":22.8,"temp_min":17.28,"temp_max":22.8,"pressure":954.89,"humidity":44.4},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":0},"wind":{"speed":11.58,"deg":196,"gust":10.5},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"36":{"dt":1391004000,"main":{"temp":27.03,"temp_min":22.8,"temp_max":27.01,"pressure":952.39,"humidity":37.7},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"clouds":{"all":15,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":15},"wind":{"speed":16.48,"deg":206,"gust":15.1},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"37":{"dt":1391014800,"main":{"temp":41.68,"temp_min":22.8,"temp_max":41.7,"pressure":950.31,"humidity":27.1},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"clouds":{"all":21,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":21},"wind":{"speed":19.14,"deg":217,"gust":12.7},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"38":{"dt":1391025600,"main":{"temp":48.13,"temp_min":41.86,"temp_max":48.07,"pressure":946.47,"humidity":28.8},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":{"all":27,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":27},"wind":{"speed":15.62,"deg":221,"gust":9.6},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"39":{"dt":1391036400,"main":{"temp":39.42,"temp_min":39.47,"temp_max":48.18,"pressure":945.8,"humidity":46.6},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":{"all":33,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":33},"wind":{"speed":9.76,"deg":217,"gust":7},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"40":{"dt":1391047200,"main":{"temp":36.48,"temp_min":36.45,"temp_max":39.47,"pressure":944.9,"humidity":53.5},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"clouds":{"all":44,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":44},"wind":{"speed":11.19,"deg":220,"gust":7.4},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"41":{"dt":1391058000,"main":{"temp":35.64,"temp_min":35.65,"temp_max":39.47,"pressure":943.31,"humidity":52.6},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"clouds":{"all":42,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":42},"wind":{"speed":9.31,"deg":230,"gust":6.4},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"42":{"dt":1391068800,"main":{"temp":34.54,"temp_min":34.57,"temp_max":35.65,"pressure":942.67,"humidity":53.4},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":64,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":64},"wind":{"speed":9.03,"deg":252,"gust":6.1},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"43":{"dt":1391079600,"main":{"temp":35.6,"temp_min":34.57,"temp_max":35.87,"pressure":943.94,"humidity":53.4},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":72,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":72},"wind":{"speed":9.91,"deg":328,"gust":6.7},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"44":{"dt":1391090400,"main":{"temp":26.78,"temp_min":26.78,"temp_max":35.56,"pressure":947.55,"humidity":77.2},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":79,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":79},"wind":{"speed":18.3,"deg":24,"gust":12},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"45":{"dt":1391101200,"main":{"temp":33.49,"temp_min":26.78,"temp_max":35.56,"pressure":949.78,"humidity":58},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":79,"low":0,"middle":18,"high":72},"wind":{"speed":8.21,"deg":45,"gust":5},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"46":{"dt":1391112000,"main":{"temp":38.25,"temp_min":33.66,"temp_max":38.21,"pressure":948.38,"humidity":50.6},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":87,"low":0,"middle":2,"high":86},"wind":{"speed":6.8,"deg":85,"gust":3.5},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"47":{"dt":1391122800,"main":{"temp":34.84,"temp_min":33.66,"temp_max":38.39,"pressure":948.29,"humidity":58.7},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":90,"low":0,"middle":1,"high":90},"wind":{"speed":5.96,"deg":99,"gust":3.6},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"48":{"dt":1391133600,"main":{"temp":31.03,"temp_min":31.05,"temp_max":34.72,"pressure":948.27,"humidity":67.5},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":79,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":79},"wind":{"speed":8.53,"deg":126,"gust":6},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"49":{"dt":1391144400,"main":{"temp":27.75,"temp_min":27.77,"temp_max":34.72,"pressure":946.79,"humidity":75.4},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":68,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":68},"wind":{"speed":8.86,"deg":135,"gust":6.6},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"50":{"dt":1391155200,"main":{"temp":26.46,"temp_min":26.49,"temp_max":27.77,"pressure":944.93,"humidity":77.7},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":54,"low":0,"middle":1,"high":54},"wind":{"speed":7.32,"deg":126,"gust":5.3},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"51":{"dt":1391166000,"main":{"temp":26.51,"temp_min":26.47,"temp_max":27.77,"pressure":943.57,"humidity":76.8},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":71,"low":0,"middle":12,"high":71},"wind":{"speed":8.25,"deg":121,"gust":6.4},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"52":{"dt":1391176800,"main":{"temp":28.17,"temp_min":26.35,"temp_max":28.13,"pressure":944.18,"humidity":72.3},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":92,"low":1,"middle":57,"high":92},"wind":{"speed":5.34,"deg":98,"gust":3},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"53":{"dt":1391187600,"main":{"temp":37.06,"temp_min":26.35,"temp_max":37.13,"pressure":943.56,"humidity":57.3},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":62,"low":8,"middle":29,"high":57},"wind":{"speed":4.06,"deg":69,"gust":1.8},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"54":{"dt":1391198400,"main":{"temp":43.34,"temp_min":37.15,"temp_max":43.36,"pressure":942.37,"humidity":52.1},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"02d"}],"clouds":{"all":7,"low":0,"middle":0,"high":6},"wind":{"speed":5.03,"deg":5,"gust":2.6},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"55":{"dt":1391209200,"main":{"temp":38.35,"temp_min":37.15,"temp_max":43.99,"pressure":944.19,"humidity":60.7},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":{"all":38,"low":0,"middle":1,"high":38},"wind":{"speed":9.05,"deg":30,"gust":6.4},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"56":{"dt":1391220000,"main":{"temp":33.87,"temp_min":33.89,"temp_max":38.34,"pressure":947.09,"humidity":66.8},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":90,"low":0,"middle":44,"high":90},"wind":{"speed":8.25,"deg":34,"gust":6.3},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"57":{"dt":1391230800,"main":{"temp":32.59,"temp_min":32.14,"temp_max":38.34,"pressure":947.46,"humidity":66.6},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":90,"low":0,"middle":60,"high":89},"wind":{"speed":9.09,"deg":23,"gust":6.7},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"58":{"dt":1391241600,"main":{"temp":30.47,"temp_min":30.43,"temp_max":32.81,"pressure":947.9,"humidity":69.8},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":96,"low":2,"middle":96,"high":52},"wind":{"speed":13.09,"deg":21,"gust":9.2},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"59":{"dt":1391252400,"main":{"temp":27.23,"temp_min":27.09,"temp_max":32.81,"pressure":948.71,"humidity":81.7},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":85,"low":1,"middle":85,"high":31},"wind":{"speed":10.63,"deg":35,"gust":9.4},"sys":{"pod":"n"}},"60":{"dt":1391263200,"main":{"temp":26.02,"temp_min":26.06,"temp_max":27.59,"pressure":951.34,"humidity":93.6},"weather":[{"id":601,"main":"Snow","description":"snow","icon":"13d"}],"clouds":{"all":99,"low":67,"middle":99,"high":80},"wind":{"speed":9.85,"deg":37,"gust":6.8},"snow":{"3h":3.7},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"61":{"dt":1391274000,"main":{"temp":27.5,"temp_min":26.04,"temp_max":27.54,"pressure":952.46,"humidity":87.2},"weather":[{"id":601,"main":"Snow","description":"snow","icon":"13d"}],"clouds":{"all":100,"low":82,"middle":99,"high":89},"wind":{"speed":7.8,"deg":42,"gust":4.6},"snow":{"3h":6.1},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"62":{"dt":1391284800,"main":{"temp":29.44,"temp_min":27.77,"temp_max":29.46,"pressure":951.54,"humidity":82.5},"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13d"}],"clouds":{"all":100,"low":99,"middle":31,"high":49},"wind":{"speed":5.94,"deg":36,"gust":3.2},"snow":{"3h":0.1},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"63":{"dt":1391295600,"main":{"temp":22.62,"temp_min":22.62,"temp_max":29.64,"pressure":952.76,"humidity":92.3},"weather":[{"id":601,"main":"Snow","description":"snow","icon":"13d"}],"clouds":{"all":89,"low":88,"middle":16,"high":25},"wind":{"speed":2.29,"deg":93,"gust":1.5},"snow":{"3h":6.2},"sys":{"pod":"d"}},"model":"gfs"}}"; 
__EOI__

my $decoded = decode_json($owm_json); 

print $decoded->{list}[0]->{weather}[0]->{description};
```

Comment: From the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm#SYNOPSIS): `$pretty_printed = $json->pretty->encode( $perl_scalar );`

Comment: And of course, there's always [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html): `print Dumper $decoded;`

Comment: That "Not an ARRAY reference" includes a line number.  You need to give us the entire error message, and also tell us what line number in your code that corresponds to.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, and it's much much much much longer than required to demonstrate the problem. Please address these issues.

Comment: Fixed the compile error, but you still need to shorten the JSON.

Answer (score 4):

Your string `$owm_json` isn't a valid Perl string.  From the short segment:

```
"{"cod":"200","city":{"id":"4270936","name":
```

This should actually be:

```
"{\"cod\":\"200\",\"city\":{\"id\":\"4270936\",\"name\":
```

You need to escape the inner quotation marks.  Try putting `use strict` at the beginning of the script and that should have caught this error.

**Update from comments:**

Looking at your JSON data, you do have an incorrect access to the descpiption field.  Here's the section you are trying to display in your example:

```
"list" : {
  "0" : {
    "weather" : [{
        "id" : 803,
        "main" : "Clouds",
        "description" : "broken clouds",
        "icon" : "04n"
      }
    ],
```

Notice that after "list" you have "0", not an array reference which would use the `[]` characters.  In your script, after `{list}` use `{0}` and not `[0]` and that should fix your issue:

```
print $decoded->{list}{0}{weather}[0]{description};
```

Comment: Instead of using all those backslashes, it's easier to use `q`: `my $foo = q({ "foo" : "bar" });`

Comment: I wanted to show the returned json code. The code I posted is what is retrieved from the API url, I guess I should have removed the quotes before posting.

Comment: @ikegami I disagree.  From what he posted it appears that his error is due to garbage data being passed to the JSON module.  If he corrects the data then the JSON module should correctly handle the input.  Adding `use strict` would have caught the error of the garbage data.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for the catch.  I've updated the answer with an explanation that should solve the OPs question.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `list` is a hash (`...,"list":{"0":{...},...`), but you try to dereference is with `->[0]` which is an array dereference.

You want:

```
$decoded->{list}{0}{weather}[0]{description}
```

instead of

```
$decoded->{list}[0]{weather}[0]{description}
```